# Why is my API data being called 53 times in React Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-hooks, fetch-api

When I call the API and want to see it in console it calls 53 times?

```js
<View style={{flex:0.5}}>
  <FlatList
        data={response}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <View >
            <Text style={{color:'red'}}>{console.log(response)}</Text>
          </View>
        )}
        keyExtractor={(item,index) => index}/>

</View>
<View style={{flex:0.1}}></View>
```

```js
const [response, setResponse] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  fetch("http://000.000.0.00:2828/blah.svc/example", requestOptions)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(result =>setResponse(result))
  .catch(error => console.log('error', error))
}, []); // empty dependency array will cause the useEffect hook to run only once
```

Also, although the data appears in the console, it does not appear in the emulator. What could be the reason for this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please have a look around and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and [Question Checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). There isn't enough information in your question for us to be able to answer it. The code shown will only call `fetch` once per element using that component function. So unless you have 53 elements...?

Comment: (It's not even clear what component the quoted code is in. Please see: [mre].)

Comment: FlatList will call renderItem for each element in response array, which will call your console.log many times

Answer (score 1):

If you want to detect why your React applications rerender you can use a couple of instruments.

1. https://github.com/welldone-software/why-did-you-render - this package will display in the console why the component was rendered.
2. profiler from https://fbflipper.com/docs/features/react-native/

Also, you can read an article about FltList optimization (https://reactnative.dev/docs/0.69/optimizing-flatlist-configuration)

You definitely need to remove `console.log` from `renderItem` and extract `renderItem` as a separate function.